# What's the right way to reset date property to nil when using CoreData and scalar property

Tags: core-data

If you have a date property in an NSManagedObject subclass like this:

```
@interface Task : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic) NSTimeInterval finishTime;

@end
```

The default value for the "finishTime" is nil. After setting the "finishTime" to some other date, is it possible to reset "finishTime" to nil?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set `nil` value through KVC:

```
   [object setValue:nil forKey:@"finishTime"];
```

Comment: Yeah, core data does all under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

Since `NSTimeInterval` is a typedef for a `double`, it's common practice to wrap it into a `NSNumber`.

Comment: This is a date property. If I don't use scalar properties for primitive data types,the finishTime will be a NSDate class,and setting it to nil will be easy.But how can I set a NSTimeInterval property to nil?

Comment: nil is a pointer to a zero memory address and cannot not be assigned to a scalar.  The analog would be simply zero.

Comment: Bug set the finishTime to 0 will make the date be "2001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000". 
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html check the "timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate" part.

Comment: It's not possible to set a scalar to nil.  If you just have to be able to use nil, you need to use an object like NSDate, NSNumber, NSString, or NSValue.